# Consuming Web API secured with JWT authentication from ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to understand how to consume an ASP.NET Core Web API secured with JWT token authentication from the an ASP.NET Core MVC web application - thanks.

Searched a couple of articles but all are consuming through Postman and externally passing JWT tokens

Comment: Please correct me if I misunderstood your requirement... when you already test the API with postman successfully now, you can then write code to send http request to that API alone with the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, we have a method like this in the MVC controller and we can use it to generate a correct jwt token.

```
private string generateJwt() {
     var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
     var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

     var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "user_name"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, "user_email"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim("role","admin"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"admin")
            };

     var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
                signingCredentials: credentials);

     return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

Then we need to add the token into the request header to when we [send a http request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Following the official document, we need to add HttpClient in Program.cs: `builder.Services.AddHttpClient();` then we can call the api with code like this:

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

public HelloController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
      _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}

public async Task<string> GetAsync() {
      var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,"https://localhost:7212/WeatherForecast")
      {
           Headers =
           {
               { HeaderNames.Authorization, "Bearer "+ accessToken}
           }
      };

      var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
      var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
      var res = "";
      if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
      {
           res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }
      return "hello" + res ;
}
```